# I came across the following sentence. Is the comma before "but" essential?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, conjunctions

Chelsea, a big club for many years now, has a habit of producing players with good potential, but most of the academy graduates do not get a chance to play for the senior squad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Observe the following clauses stand alone as complete sentences.

> Chelsea, a big club for many years now, has a habit of producing players with good potential.
>
> Most of the academy graduates do not get a chance to play for the senior squad.

Thus to join the two and form a compound sentence requires both a comma and a conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

If there was no comma, the conjunction "but" would join the *shortest* possible clause before it, i.e. "good potential".

A sentence like "Chelsea, a big club for many years now, has a habit of producing players with good potential but poor motivation." does not need the comma, because "but" is comparing the shortest possible adjacent phrases, "good potential" and "poor motivation". But in the OP's sentence, the clause referred to by the word "but" starts at the beginning of the sentence.